# implements Closeable or implements AutoCloseable

Tags: java, java-io

I'm in the process of learning Java and I cannot find any good explanation on the `implements Closeable` and the `implements AutoCloseable` interfaces.

When I implemented an `interface Closeable`, my Eclipse IDE created a method `public void close() throws IOException`.

I can close the stream using `pw.close();` without the interface. But, I cannot understand how I can implement the`close()` method using the interface. And, what is the purpose of this interface?

Also I would like to know: how can I check if `IOstream` was really closed?

I was using the basic code below

```
import java.io.*;

public class IOtest implements AutoCloseable {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

    File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);

    System.out.println("file has been created");

    pw.println("file has been created");

}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {


}
```

Comment: I think all has already been said, but maybe you are interested in the following article about try on ressources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html . This might also be helpful to understand the given answers.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the code you have posted, you don't need to implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

You only have to (or should) implement [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) or [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) if you are about to implement your own `PrintWriter`, which handles files or any other resources which needs to be closed.

In your implementation, it is enough to call `pw.close()`. You should do this in a finally block:

```
PrintWriter pw = null;
try {
   File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
   pw = new PrintWriter(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("bad things happen");
} finally {
   if (pw != null) {
      try {
         pw.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
   }
}
```

The code above is Java 6 related. In Java 7 this can be done more elegantly (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13141382/714965)).

Comment: Why only with a `PrintWriter`? Especially `AutoClosable` objects can be used in many more circumstances than just `PrintWriter`s...

Comment: You are absolutely right. The question was about `PrintWriter` so I mentioned it to be more specific.

Comment: Why describe the situation for Java 6 in the context of `AutoCloseable`? Better show a `try-with-resources` instead …

Answer (score 259):

[`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) (introduced in Java 7) makes it possible to use the [***try-with-resources***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) idiom:

```
public class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {

    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Closing!");
    }

}
```

Now you can say:

```
try (MyResource res = new MyResource()) {
    // use resource here
}
```

and JVM will call `close()` automatically for you.

[`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) is an older interface. <del>For some reason</del> To preserve backward compatibility, language designers decided to create a separate one.  This allows not only all `Closeable` classes (like streams throwing `IOException`) to be used in try-with-resources, but also allows throwing more general checked exceptions from `close()`.

When in doubt, use `AutoCloseable`, users of your class will be grateful.

Comment: The reason is simple: `Closeable.close()` throws `IOException`. A lot of `close()` methods that could benefit of try-with-resources throw other checked exceptions (eg `java.sql.Connection.close()` so `AutoCloseable.close()` throws `Exception`. Changing the existing `Closeable` contract would break all existing applications/library relying on the contract that `close()` only throws `IOException` and not all (checked) exceptions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: +1, thanks. I corrected my answer to reflect your suggestions and comments.

Comment: And also: `Closeable.close()` is required to be idempotent. `AutoCloseable.close()` is not, although it is still strongly recommended.

Comment: Also, don't use the default `public void close( ) throws Exception` -- use a more specific exception if you can (e..g IOException)

Comment: Except this breaks backwards compatibility, because things that used to be Closable (like `javax.sql.Connection`) are now *only* AutoClosable, so won't work with libraries (like commons-io) anymore, because they only support Closable (Because they need to compile with non-Java 7 JDK) .

Comment: "When in doubt, use `AutoCloseable`, users of your class will be grateful." Wouldn't users prefer `Closeable`, since that guarantees idempotence and throws the more specific IOException?

Comment: `Closeable` does not *guarantee* idempotence.  It *requires* idempotence in a user's implementation of the `close()` method. And whether `IOException` is more specific/appropriate depends on the use case.

Comment: "When in doubt, use AutoCloseable, users of your class will be grateful" - this doen't give any gain since older `Closable` was retrofitted to implement `AutoCloseable` too.

Comment: You can also use Closable in a try-with-resources, as Closable is a subinterface of AutoClosable

Comment: This is not true for java 8 at least, `closeable` also works with the try-with-resources idiom

Answer (score 95):

[`Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), and is specifically dedicated to IO streams: it throws `IOException` instead of `Exception`, and is idempotent, whereas `AutoCloseable` doesn't provide this guarantee.

This is all explained in the javadoc of both interfaces.

Implementing `AutoCloseable` (or `Closeable`) allows a class to be used as a resource of the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct introduced in Java 7, which allows closing such resources automatically at the end of a block, without having to add a `finally` block which closes the resource explicitly.

Your class doesn't represent a closeable resource, and there's absolutely no point in implementing this interface: an `IOTest` can't be closed. It shouldn't even be possible to instantiate it, since it doesn't have any instance method. Remember that implementing an interface means that there is a **is-a** relationship between the class and the interface. You have no such relationship here.

Comment: Just implement **Closable** for streams-related classes, and **AutoClosable** for others which requires autoclose feature.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the small example

```
public class TryWithResource {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (TestMe r = new TestMe()) {
            r.generalTest();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("From Exception Block");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("From Final Block");
        }
    }
}



public class TestMe implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" From Close -  AutoCloseable  ");
    }

    public void generalTest() {
        System.out.println(" GeneralTest ");
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
GeneralTest 
From Close -  AutoCloseable  
From Final Block
```

Comment: It is better to write the output also so there will be no need for a trial project for such a short code.

Comment: In the close() method, don't we need to close the resource explicitly? There is only print statement perhaps.

Comment: @ShaileshWaghmare yes exactly. but for the testing purpose i have mention in the Code snip.

Comment: @LovaChittumuri So will it be like `this.close()` or something in code?, because it is called automatically.(just to be sure)

Answer (score 10):

Recently I have read a Java SE 8 Programmer Guide ii Book.

I found something about the difference between `AutoCloseable` vs `Closeable`.

The `AutoCloseable` interface was introduced in Java 7. Before that, another interface
existed called `Closeable`. It was similar to what the language designers wanted, with the
following exceptions:

- `Closeable` restricts the type of exception thrown to `IOException`.
- `Closeable` requires implementations to be idempotent.

The language designers emphasize backward compatibility. Since changing the existing
interface was undesirable, they made a new one called `AutoCloseable`. This new
interface is less strict than `Closeable`. Since `Closeable` meets the requirements for
`AutoCloseable`, it started implementing `AutoCloseable` when the latter was introduced.

Comment: Instead of saying that "This new interface is less strict than `Closeable`", I'd suggest saying "This new interface can be used in more general contexts, where the exception thrown during closing is not necessarily an IOException". In the Java universe, being "less strict" has a negative vibe about it.

Answer (score 7):

The `try-with-resources` Statement.

The `try-with-resources statement` is a `try` statement that declares one or more resources. A `resource` is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The `try-with-resources statement` ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable`, which includes all objects which implement `java.io.Closeable`, can be used as a resource.

The following example reads the first line from a file. It uses an instance of `BufferedReader` to read data from the file. `BufferedReader` is a resource that must be closed after the program is finished with it:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

In this example, the resource declared in the try-with-resources statement is a BufferedReader. The declaration statement appears within parentheses immediately after the try keyword. The class `BufferedReader`, in Java SE 7 and later, implements the interface `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. Because the `BufferedReader` instance is declared in a try-with-resource statement, it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly (as a result of the method `BufferedReader.readLine` throwing an `IOException`).

Prior to Java SE 7, you can use a `finally` block to ensure that a resource is closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly. The following example uses a `finally` block instead of a `try-with-resources` statement:

```
static String readFirstLineFromFileWithFinallyBlock(String path)
                                                     throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) br.close();
    }

}
```

Please [refer to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).