# object is not closed properly. Whats is meant by it in scanner?

Tags: java

I used scanner for the first time. I got an error @ finish, saying that finish is not closed properly. What is meant by that. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputvalue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner finish = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = finish.nextInt();
        while (i < j) {
            System.out.print("hai");
            i = i + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First off horrible code formatting. And also.... `finish.close();` I don't think you are getting an error but you are simply getting a warning?. When you don't close a resource stream like a `Scanner`/`InputStream`/`etc...` you will get a `resource leak`

Comment: add `finish.close()` to avoid resource leak

Answer (score 0):

The compilator warns you about a potential leak of memory. You have two solutions when encountering this problem.

### [java-7](/questions/tagged/java-7) and latter

Use a `try-with-resources` block that will automatically close your stream. That'll prevent your program from having a leak in its resources.

```
int i = 0, j;
try(Scanner finish = new Scanner(System.in)){
    j = finish.nextInt();
}
while (i < j) {
    System.out.print("hai");
    i = i + 1;
}
```

---

### [java-6](/questions/tagged/java-6) and earlier

Use a `try-finally` and within the latter check if your object is null. If it's not, close it manually.

```
int i = 0, j;
Scanner finish = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    j = finish.nextInt();
} finally {
    if (finish != null) {
        finish.close();
    }
}
while (i < j) {
    System.out.print("hai");
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Scanner` implements `Closeable` interface which has a close method. All the classes implementing this interface represent that they are using resources that needs to be closed. You should therefore clsoe `Scanner`. One way of doing this is in the `predestroy` method as:

```
@PreDestroy
public void preDestroy {
    scanner.close();
}
```

The other way would be to close scanner at the end of your code as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    Scanner finish = new Scanner(System.in);
    int j = finish.nextInt();
    finish.close();
    while (i < j) {
        System.out.print("hai");
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Read more about `Closeable` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141302/implements-closeable-or-implements-autocloseable)

Comment: Actually, the proper method is to use try-with-resources

Comment: Yes of course! I was just attempting to show the use case

Comment: A class consisting entirely of a `main()` is hardly a candidate for an `@PreDestroy` method, and unless `scanner` is rather pointlessly made into a static member of the class your suggestion won't even compile.