# java.lang.StackOverflowError for gson get methods

Tags: java, gson, jpql

My pet class looks like this(haven't taken getters and setters).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pet")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findById", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE p.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findByName", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE p.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findByBirth", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE p.birth = :birth")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findBySpecies", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE p.species = :species")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Pet.findByDeath", query = "SELECT p FROM Pet p WHERE p.death = :death")})
public class Pet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "birth", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birth;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "species", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String species;
    @Column(name = "death")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date death;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pet")
    private Collection<Event> eventCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Owner owner;

    public Pet() {
    }

    public Pet(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pet(Integer id, String name, Date birth, String species) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.species = species;
    }
```

I have this gson method

```
@GET 
    @Path("/living")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getLivingPets(){
        return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(pf.getLivingPets())).build();
    }
```

and my database facade method

```
public List<Pet> getLivingPets() {

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p where p.death is null");

            return (List<Pet>) q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error

> type Exception report
>
> message java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeValue(JsonWriter.java:642)
>     com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.open(JsonWriter.java:325)
>     com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:308)
>     com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:1018)
>     com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `Pet` class?

Comment: I have now add the pet class code

Comment: It's may be a problem of type (FutureTypeAdapter); conversion in json don't know how to adapt a certain type (but I don't know which)

Comment: Maybe the Event or Owner has a reference to one or more Pet, and cyclic resolution happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first change If you need to close a stream, then best practice would be to use the try-with-resources statement [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141302/implements-closeable-or-implements-autocloseable#answer-13141382)

```
    try (EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select p from Pet p where p.death is null");

        return (List<Pet>) q.getResultList();
    }
```

version 1 send only dto send only the field you need

```
@GET 
@Path("/living")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getLivingPets(){
    return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(pf.getLivingPets().stream().map(Dto::new).collect(Collectors.toList()))).build();
}
```

//adn created class your DTO

```
public class Dto {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;

    public Dto(Pet pet) {
        this.id= pet.getId();
        this.name= pet.getName();
    }
}
```

version 2 create TypeAdapter where is the feedback reference to Pet

```
@GET 
@Path("/living")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getLivingPets(){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Owner.class, new PetAdapter()).create();
    return Response.ok().entity(gson.toJson(pf.getLivingPets())).build();
}
```

created PetAdapter

```
public class PetAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Owner> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Owner value) throws IOException {

        out.beginObject();
        out.name("id");
        out.value(value.getId());
        out.endObject();

        //NOT USE PET
    }

    @Override
    public Owner read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```